# Clang stdio,h file not found

Tags: c, clang, stdio

I installed clang with Visual Studio and then built the highlighted project as it's said in the documentation.

[image]

The build was successful, however when I try this:

```
clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=core.DivideZero test.c
```

It says:

```
test.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried many suggestions but nothing worked.

However if I do something like this it works

```
clang --analyze text.c
```

I don't know if this uses all the available checkers. I need to write my own checker and test it...

Any ideas?

Output of `clang --version`

```
clang version 7.0.0 (trunk 322536)
Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\path\build\Debug\bin
```

Comment: You need to set your path in your cmd.exe user environment to include the clang install path and insure the include search path matches where `/path/to/clang/include` is located. You should also be able to add `-I/path/to/clang/include` to your `clang -cc1 ...` command line (double check that clang uses `-I` for that purpose -- or use the option is provides)

Comment: How do I find the "include search path"?

Comment: It is an environment variable generally set by clang or VS (they will each have a default for where they look for include files). Each also provides a command line option to specify where to look for them. You will have to look at wherever clang installed to (e.g. `c:\Program Files\clang\...` or `c:\Program Files(x86)\clang\...` to find out where that is. See [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Comment: From your output above `InstalledDir: C:\path\build\Debug\bin` check under `c:\path` (which seems like are really weird place to install to)

Comment: Have you considered [reading the clang FAQ](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html)?

Comment: @David. I tried your suggestion and it worked meaning that it doesn't say that stdio.h is missing. But now it's telling me to add it even though it's on the first line..

Comment: Also, running another example it says that i have C99. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: All compilers have a way of configuring everything from the command line. What the other answer says makes sense. I've never used clang, so I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but all compilers work more-or-less the same. You just have to consult there documentation to figure out what each wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have an idea. Remove `-cc1` or `<stdio.h>`. According to [the clang FAQ](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html) this is your error. It states quite explicitly, giving your precise example:

> ```
> $ clang -cc1 hello.c
> hello.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
> #include <stdio.h>
>          ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

Reading on, it gives other alternative solutions, as well as a useful explanation, which you should certainly read in its entirety, since it's our job as programmers to read the manuals for the technology we use.

> `clang -cc1` is the frontend, `clang` is the driver. The driver invokes the frontend with options appropriate for your system. To see these options, run:
>
> ```
> $ clang -### -c hello.c
> ```
>
> Some `clang` command line options are driver-only options, some are frontend-only options. Frontend-only options are intended to be used only by clang developers. **Users should not run `clang -cc1` directly, because `-cc1` options are not guaranteed to be stable.**
>
> If you want to use a frontend-only option (“a `-cc1` option”), for example `-ast-dump`, then you need to take the `clang -cc1` line generated by the driver and add the option you need. Alternatively, you can run `clang -Xclang <option> ...` to force the driver pass `<option>` to `clang -cc1`.

The emphasis is mine. This should give you enough guidance to get what you need done.

Comment: yes I have. But That's the only way to run a  custom checker.

Comment: It not clear at all.
"If you want to use a frontend-only option (“a -cc1 option”), for example -ast-dump, then you need to take the clang -cc1 line generated by the driver and add the option you need. " 

What -cc1 generated by the driver?

Comment: ... and in case you miss my question, here's the part you stopped short of, beginning with "alternatively", which tells you a SECOND option: "Alternatively, you can run `clang -Xclang <option> ...` to force the driver pass `<option>` to `clang -cc1`."

Comment: I already tried all these options and ended up telling me to include <stdio.h> while it was already inserted. However, I found an workaround without stdio. But I will accept your answer, bc you tried to help

Comment: I'd love to have seen what you tried, since as I'm sure you're aware, experiments can be flawed. Please show the output of `clang -### -c hello.c` (where `hello.c` is any file), and the command you're running.

Comment: The output is way to long. The first option displayed is exactly "-cc1".

Comment: The following are: -triple" "i686-pc-windows-msvc19.12.25831" "-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-mincremental-linker-compatible" "-disable-free" "-main-file-name" "open.c" "-mrelocation-model" "static" "-mthread-model" "posix" "-mdisable-fp-elim" "-fmath-errno" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-target-cpu" "pentium4"...etc.

I have specified from where to get the libraries with -isystem "path_to_lib".

The command was something like clang -cc1 -isystem "path" --analyze....